# How to get custom product attribute(programatically created) drop down values in a phtml in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, custom-attributes, drop-downs

Created a custom product attribute by programmatically.
Now, I need to get the drop down option values in a phtml page.

```
$seriesname  =   $child->getAttributeText('series');

$values =   $product->getResource()->getAttribute('series')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

$_attributeValue = $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('series')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());
```

Used the above three methods, but I didn't get all the values. I only get 'Select Option'. It has three option values, option1, option2, option3

Comment: Which block used for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('series');
if($attr->usesSource()) {
    $allOptions = $attr->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
    var_dump($allOptions);die;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by below code

```
$_attributeValue = $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('series')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());
$values =   $product->getResource()->getAttribute('series')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```